# Error when passing filename per reference (C)

Tags: c

I need to pass a char pointer and filename per reference, and allocate a size for the pointer in that same function. (in the program it reads the size it needs to allocate from the file).

I created the file and also checked it in a hex editor, and it does exist.

I have tried to run it on GCC and Cygwin, it doesn't seem to be a compiler specific problem.

The following code is just the barebones, but still contains the same error:
GDB tells me it's a segfault caused by the file not existing. ("No such file or directory").

Where did I go wrong?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 50
#define NAME "name"

int loadFile(char** board, char* filename);

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  char* board;
  char* filename = NAME;

  loadFile(&board, filename);

  board[49] = '\0';

  return 0;
}


int loadFile(char** board, char* filename)
{
  FILE* source = fopen(filename, "rb");

  if(source == NULL)
  {
    printf("Error loading file.\n");
    return -1;
  }

  *board = malloc(SIZE);

  if(fread(*board, sizeof(char), SIZE, source) != SIZE)
  {
    fclose(source);
    printf("Error loading file.\n");
    return -2;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: How come you first posted this as `board = malloc(SIZE);` and then changed to `*board = malloc(SIZE);`? Which is the original? Is this not a copy-paste of the actual code?

Comment: Well, if the file indeed doesn't exist, `loadFile` returns without assigning a valid value to `*board`, but you then attempt to treat it as such (by writing the null terminator in `main`). So the segfault is expected. As for the file not being there; (I'm assuming a Windows environment) how exactly are you running it? Are you using an IDE, or `cmd.exe`?

Comment: you are providing the address of a pointer that you declared on the stack to a function that gets called on top of it. try dynamically allocating board.

Comment: @IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII Yes, he is, and that's valid. The other way round would be wrong.

Comment: @szczurcio the other way around would be 100% wrong because it would be returning a pointer to a value that has been destroyed. but in this case also cant be a good idea either

Comment: @Lundin: It Was a copy paste, but I did some formatting in here and accidentally deleted the '*'.

Comment: @szczurcio That explains the segfault, thank you! I still don't know where I am wrong on the filename, I have checked and checked and the problem must lie in the code, not the file.

Comment: @BigBadWolf Ok just making sure you aren't re-typing the whole code here manually :) Yeah it sounds crazy but some actually do.

Comment: @szczurcio You should post that as an answer. I was about to point out the very same thing but you beat me to it :)

Comment: @IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII One could argue that `malloc`ing memory in a function then expecting the caller to free it is a bad idea, but passing a `char**` so the function can modify the underlying `char*` is perfectly fine. The library functions `strtox` do exactly this (the `char** endptr` argument).

Comment: @Lundin It's not really an answer yet because I asked for clarification to find out how OP is running the program, because this might help explain why the file cannot be found.

Comment: OP, another idea off the top of my head is the stupid "hide extensions" feature in Windows. It's possible that you're trying to open "name" but in reality your file is called for example "name.txt" (but in Windows Exporer you still see it as "name" because of this bug/feature).

Comment: @szczurcio my bad at first glance I thought he is passing char* to function to copy stuff to it. that would overwrite variables on the stack that would come after char* declaration as well as the calee function stack

Comment: @szczurcio forgot to answer that! I am compiling and running it with cygwin64 on windows 10, as well as with gcc on debian 32bit. Running it on two different systems and compilers. Same errors.

Comment: @szczurcio Update: I am indeed getting the Segfault in the function `fread(*board, sizeof(char), SIZE, source) != SIZE` . I tried to put a printf() between that line and the return to the main, and it never prints. I am none the wiser, except that now I know I'm not getting the segfault from using the failed file.

Comment: I don't believe so, you're not doing anything if `fopen` fails because you have a check for this. Can you ensure that the file is opened correctly, i.e. `fopen` doesn't return `NULL`? Simply check this one thing, ignore reading anything from the stream for now.

Answer (score 2):

Following many comments with suggestions, I have seen strange things when a constant char literal is passed:

```
#define NAME "name"
char* filename = NAME;
```

This assigns a pointer to a constant char literal to `filename`. Please try:

```
#define NAME "name"
char filename[] = NAME;
```

Comment: What does this matter? Both are arrays of `char`, except that the second one is allocated on the caller's stack and as such is mutable.

Comment: @ szczurcio, it _shouldn't_ matter but I have seen (and experienced) it happen.

Answer (score 1):

Check your status values:

```
rv = loadFile(&board, filename);
if (rv == -1) {
  perror("Error opening file");
  return 1;
}
```

This should (hopefully) give you an error message you can troubleshoot further. Using a `const char *` as an argument to `fopen()` should be OK.